# Feedburner subscriber count and my RSS reader app

Tags: rss, feed, feedburner

I'm going to create a Feed reader app. When a user requests a feed, the feed is downloaded (or loaded from cache) on **my** server, then it **downloaded** from **my** server to user's PC/smartphone.

But I think Google Feedburner won't know that, and won't show real Subscriber count for admins. Is that right?

What should I do if I want google to count readers (also who are using my app) correctly?

Answer (score 1):

What your basically talking about is creating a web proxy for the feed, and then serving the proxied feed to your users. By default this method will not update the feedburner subscriber counts as they will only see 1 unique visitor requesting the feed, however there are methods to inform google that you are requesting the feed on behalf of a certain number of subscribers.

> In the case of stand-alone feed readers, that user has an application
>   running on their computer which fetches the feed repeatedly throughout
>   the day. We look at characteristics of those requests, and
>   differentiate between repeated requests from the same person (as
>   indicated by regular polling intervals, consistent IP addresses, and
>   common user agents) and different requests (where one or more of the
>   previous data points vary). In the case of web-based feed readers (My
>   Yahoo, Google Reader, Bloglines, Pageflakes, etc.), those services
>   retrieve the feed repeatedly throughout the day, but do so on behalf
>   of multiple people. Almost all of these services report to us how many
>   of their users are subscribed to the feed. At the end of the day, we
>   tally up how many stand-alone feed readers are subscribed, and add
>   them to the web-based users. The end result is the total subscriber
>   number we report. (I’m leaving a few details out; see below for a more
>   complete answer.)

from [here](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2007/08/16/why-does-my-feedburner-subscriber-count-fluctuate/)

Comment: `Almost all of these services report to us how many of their users are subscribed to the feed`... So how to tell google how many of my users are subscribed to the feed?!?